# Excel Index Match for multiple conditions evaluates correctly with F9 but not in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I have an index match formula that evaluates correctly if I use F9, however when I actually press enter it returns #N/A.

The formula is designed to perform a vlookup on two conditions:

```
=INDEX(Table2[#All], MATCH(1,([@countries]=Table2[[#All],[countries]])*([@item]=Table2[[#All],[item]]),0),7)
```

The workbook setup, is two sheets. In Table1, the rows countries and item are being matched to those values in Table2 and then the 7th column extracted and returned.

Can anyone explain what subtlety I'm missing, I've never seen a formula evaluate correctly manually and then break when entered.

Example Sheet

http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g6b77d4bb9dab75c8999661037709c740263a1b35d

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is an array formula, you need to finish it by CTRL+ALT+ENTER instead of just ENTER.
So giving the error message is the expected result, apparently excel manage press of F9 in a more intelligent way.